# Google Spell Checker in Python

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2009, source-code

Joel mentioned on podcast #74 at one of the DevDays, someone wrote the google spell checker in python and Jon Skeet tried to write the same algorithm in C#.

Does anyone know where I can find both code samples?

Comment: Belongs on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Peter Norvig's Python code](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) is easy to find.

I haven't found time to get back to the C# version I'm afraid, although other people have posted their own C# versions. I'm going for one which uses the same ideas but is actually *readable* rather than just as short as it can be. When I eventually get round to finishing it, I'll [blog](http://msmvps.com/jon.skeet) about it.

Oh, and to counter what seems to be a popular myth - this *isn't* the Google spelling checker.  It's a spelling checker which shows some interesting ideas. Google Web Search doesn't run in 50 lines of Perl, either :)

Comment: Looking forward to it.  I suspected that provided link was the source code I was looking for, but needed to verify it.  I have very limited exposure to python.

Comment: Did you ever finish the port Jon?

Comment: @ChrisS: I don't think so, I'm afraid. I got distracted :(